# Must one fast if her stomach hurts?

Tags: fast-days, choleh-sick

If someone's stomach hurts on Sheva asar b'tammuz, should she fast? Or do these extenuating circumstances free her from her obligation?

Comment: It's hard to imagine there's a specific categorical exemption of "stomach pain".

Answer (score 6):

On 17 Tammuz, like on Tzom Gedalyia and 10 Tevet, the law is that

> **One who is ill, even if his life is not in danger, should not fast**
> ([Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 121:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.121.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

adds the Mishna Brura ([550:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.550.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.550.4&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en))

> Indeed **it is prohibited for one who suffers greatly by the fast to be
> stringent upon himself and fast**.

As to what considers "ill" and "suffers greatly", one should ask his or her Rav, who can ask further questions and personalize an answer for the particular person.

*Refua shlema* !

Answer (score -5):

According to Jewish law no. According to science yes. A middle path would be to fast according to Jewish law on Jewish holidays but on a regular basis, fast according to biology (on every other day of the week).

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why Jewish law prohibits it and why science allows it?

Comment: Science doesn't tell you what to do. It may tell you what is likely to happen if you do or don't do something.

Comment: @YosefZaghi Because according to Jewish law one should fast unless one is terminally ill. A stomach cramp would not constitute as being terminally ill.

Comment: @Alex yes, but I am telling you (readers) that it is good to fast every other day. When you fast your body is repairing itself. Also, sufficient sleep and a gallon of water a day are very useful.

Comment: Are your first two sentences an answer to the first sentence in the question, or the second sentence in the question?

Comment: "Because according to Jewish law one should fast unless one is terminally ill." This is patently false. See, for example, the answer right above you, which says explicitly (with a valid source) that a non-terminally ill person need not fast.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that is correct. The second sentence is my own opinion.

Comment: @Salmononius2 You may be correct.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted so much. It answers the question, albeit without sources.